# CodeIgniter Error: "The action you have requested is not allowed."

Tags: php, codeigniter

In my application I have a contact us form in http://www.example.com. If i am sending from www.example.com in the url then the form is submitted. If I send the form from example.com in the url the form is giving me a Error: "The action you have requested is not allowed."

I think the problem is because i enabled csrf protection in codeigniter config file.When i make it false it is working good.How can i resolve this issue when the csrf protection is enabled.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Could you kindly explain why CSRF protection is wanted in your usecase? Maybe this will already answer the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just place this line of code in your form to solve this.

```
<input type="hidden" name="<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_token_name(); ?>" value="<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_hash(); ?>">
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Should I enable csrf or disable it

Comment: Now you can enable it

Comment: It doesn't work .it is giving me the same error.I previously used form_open() so that the above line of code will generate automatically.

Comment: Ya sure I will do that

Comment: I am really sorry ! I will edit the post with all the form code. So you  can  detect the problem  easily.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99186/discussion-between-john-pabba-and-amit-rajput).

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your form:

```
<input type="hidden" name="csrf_hash_name" value="your-hash-value-here">
```